# How can I set up Trac to run on a webserver?

Tags: configuration, web-server, fastcgi, trac

I'm setting up Trac for a project on a Windows Server 2003 which already has Apache2.2 and Virtual SVN already installed and in use. I managed to install Trac and run it on its in built stand alone server but I can't seem to get it to run on the webserver. I have tried various tutorials and guides all in vain. I have installed various additions into Apache2.2 but still Trac cannot be accesed via http.
Anyone with a step by step approach that I can use to configure Apache2.2 so that it can work with Trac and I'm able to acccess it via a url?

Comment: Can you give any more details about the problem other than "Trac cannot be accessed via http"?  When you try to access Trac, do you get a standard 404 page or an error from Trac?  Is there anything in the webserver's log or Trac's log to indicate that it saw your request?  Can you share a link to the specific installation instructions that you are following and indicate how far you made it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this guide?
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindowsIisAjp

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed the latest trac (12.1) under Windows XP with the use of Apache 2.2, python 2.7 and mod_wsgi.  I used standard installation instructions from the trac's website. I used mod_sapi to authenticate users against local NT domain. I don't remember the particularities now, I only remember that I took me less then a working day to find all the required software, modules, and set it all up.

I'm not in the office right now, so I cannot paste in the config I have.  If you wish, send me an email to max(-at-)kosyakov.net, I'll send you back the configs and modules once I'm back in the office.